# Hash inside \Q and \E

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to match a pattern with perl that contains a hash (or pound character '#'):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

if( $#ARGV + 1 != 2 ) {
    die "ERROR: Number of command line arguments is not 2";
}
my $input = $ARGV[ 0 ];
my $output = $ARGV[ 1 ];

open( my $ifh, "<:encoding(UTF-8):crlf", "$input" )
    || die "ERROR: Failed to open input file: $!";
my $content = do { local $/; <$ifh> };

open( my $ofh, ">:encoding(UTF-8):crlf", "$output" )
    || die "ERROR: Failed to open output file: $!";

eval { # GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLER BEGIN

{ ( ( my $fix, my $dat, my $rest ) = ( $content
=~ / ^ ( \Q# started on \E ) ([^\n]+) \n{3}
       (.*)
     $ /xs
) ) || die "ERROR: No match";
print $ofh __LINE__ . "\tDate\t$dat\n";
$content = $rest; }

}; if( $@ ) { print $ofh "$@____________\n"; print $ofh "$content"; } # GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLER END
```

This gives the following error message:

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/ ^ (  <-- HERE \#\ started\ on\ \\E\ \)\ \(\[\^\\n\]\+\)\ \\n\{3\}\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \(\.\*\)\
\ \ \ \ \ \$\ / at ./example.pl line 25.
```

However, if I change it like this, then it works perfectly:

```
{ ( ( my $fix, my $dat, my $rest ) = ( $content
=~ / ^ ( \# \Q started on \E ) ([^\n]+) \n{3}
       (.*)
     $ /xs
) ) || die "ERROR: No match";
print $ofh __LINE__ . "\tDate\t$dat\n";
$content = $rest; }
```

I would prefer, however, to keep the hashtag inside the `\Q` and `\E` block.

So the question is, does `\Q` and `\E` not escape everything inside it? Or what is wrong here?

Comment: `if( $#ARGV + 1 != 2 ) { die "Error.." }` can also be written `die "Error.." if @ARGV != 2;`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Sorry, I'm not a native Perl-speaker

Comment: I recommend against using `\Q\E` except when surrounding just an interpolating var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` inside a regex with `/x` introduces a comment. You need to backslash it even inside `\Q...\E` under `/x`.

BTW, the part inside `eval` can be made a bit more readable by using `or` instead of `||` for flow control (it's a recommended practice, anyway). Also, don't relay on `$@` to be set after an error, there were bugs in older Perl versions that caused it to not be set properly. Instead, return a true value from the `eval` and check it, e.g.

```perl
{
    ( my $fix, my $dat, my $rest )
        = $content =~ / ^ ( \Q \# started on \E ) ([^\n]+) \n{3}
                        (.*)
                        $
                      /xs or die "ERROR: No match";
1 } or do { # Handle the exception...
```

*Update:* It's a bug in Perl. Note that it hits only when an octothorpe is used literally, i.e. you can store it in a variable and it will work:

```perl
my $octothorpe = '#';
print 'a # b' =~ /(\Q $octothorpe \E) b/x
```

Comment: According to [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#/x-and-/xx) it seems like you should not need to escape `#` if placed inside a `\Q ... \E`. Is this a bug in the documentation?

Comment: Seems so. Let me report it.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18981).

Comment: I tried it but now my output file contains an error message written by the exception handler: `ERROR: No match at ./example.pl line 22, <$ifh> line 1.`. I tried to put spaces after and before `\#` but none of the combinations worked.

Comment: So it's not a bug in the documentation, it's a bug in Perl :)

Comment: OK, I'll leave it outside \Q and \E

Comment: @z32a7ul: According to the comments on the report, it could work if you use `my $octothorpe = '#';` and then `/\Q $octothorpe \E/x`.